# Labels appear twice using tick.mirror in horizontal bars

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create a horizontal bar chart using ChartJS and I want to have the labels inside the bars. The configuration I'm using is the following:

```
var chartElm = document.getElementById('chart-e117165e');
var chartObj = new Chart(chartElm, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["This is one reason","This is another reason","This will end the chat"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Select",
            data: [299,296,296],
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)","rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)","rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)"],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        title: {
            text: "Select",
            display: true,
        },
        scales: {
            yAxis: {
                ticks: {
                    mirror: true
                }
            }
        },
        events: [],
        legend: {
            display: true,
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: ''
        },
        layout: {},
        animation: {}
    }
});
```

For some reason though, I'm getting two labels, both inside and outside the bar:

[image]

I'm already using the latest 4.3.3 version.

Am I missing something here? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, what's your expected result? Remove the label from outside bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you want to display the y-axis label within the bar chart only.

From the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.0.1/migration/v4-migration.html#charts),

> Default scale override has been removed if the configured scale starts with x/y. Defining xAxes in your config will now create a second scale instead of overriding the default x axis.

You should use the `y` which is the default y-axis instead of `yAxis`.

```
scales: {
  y: {
    ticks: {
      mirror: true,
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lt2kbc?file=index.html)